# Python 3 - wait for all .exe instances to close before opening more in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I hope that title is clear. Please consider the below:

```
import subprocess
import time


for i in range(0, 20, 5):

    print(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    process1 = subprocess.Popen(["G:\\mydir\\myfile.exe"])
    process1.wait()

    time.sleep(3)
    process2 = subprocess.Popen(["G:\\mydir\\myfile.exe"])
    process2.wait()

    time.sleep(3)
    process3 = subprocess.Popen(["G:\\mydir\\myfile.exe"])
    process3.wait()
```

...the purpose of this code should be:

1) Increment for 0, 20 by 5.

2) For each pass of the loop, open three instances of an executable that will do some stuff.

3) Once all three have finished executing and closed, complete the next iteration of the loop.

...the idea is that there will never be more than 3 instances open, but always at least 1 during each pass of the loop.

However, with the above code, each of the three processes is waiting for the previous one to end. So there are still three .exe instances per loop, however there is never more than one open at any one time.

What do I need to do so I get the desired behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ``.wait()`` for the suproccesses after opening *all 3* of them?

Comment: how do i assign a wait for all three?

Comment: What do you mean by a wait for all three? You already wait for all three, just at the wrong point in time. Do all three ``.wait()`` after opening all subprocesses.

Comment: loop 1) open three .exe instances...when all close, make a second pass of the loop and again open three more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for each subprocess directly after creating it, wait for all subprocesses at the end of the loop. Both can be done in a nested loop.

```
import subprocess
import time


for i in range(0, 20, 5):
    print(i)
    child_processes = []
    # open all subprocesses
    for _ in range(3):
        time.sleep(3)
        child_processes.append(subprocess.Popen(["G:\\mydir\\myfile.exe"]))

    # wait on all subprocesses
    for child_process in child_processes:
        child_process.wait()
```